# Making a ton of variables in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm wondering if there is a way to make a ton of variables quickly with a loop or quickly in c++

say for example your trying to make a ton of variables called `item1` through `item100` so that you can edit any item in there that you want, how can someone create all those variables, without having to type every individual one manually?

Is that possible or another way to achieve similar results?

Comment: Look in your C++ manual for the term 'array.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array:

```
std::array<int, 100> items;
```

or

```
int items[100];
```

Now you can access each item from a zero-based index:

```
items[0] = 0;
items[66] = 0xffff;
/* etc */
```

I guess I prefer the `std::array` if it's available. Iterators and the bounds-checked `at` function are useful.

Answer (score 6):

Define an array instead of ton of different variables:

```
 Type array[100];
```

Or better use `std::vector` instead:

```
 std::vector<Type>  v(100);   //#include <vector>
```

Or if it is fixed-size, then `std::array`:

```
 std::array<Type, 100>  a;   //#include <array>  //only C++11
```

Search for arrays and vector in C++. You will see lots of topics on this site.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "better" but +1 since, by your photo, you're about one year old and this answer shows incredible insight for that age :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
int items[100];
```

This gives you item0 to item99 like this

```
item[0] = 10;
item[99] = 6;
```

etc...

This code is portable between C & C++ unlike the other array or vector based options.

If you want to loop through you can do it like this

```
// e.g. set all items to zero
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    items[i] = 0; 
}
```